# Displaying listbox control from another page ASP.Net VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox, master-pages

I need to display the values from a listbox on a content page in a textbox on a masterpage in ASP.Net using VB.Net

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Dim txt As Textbox = DirectCast(Master.FindControl("yourTextbox"), Textbox)
txt.text = "your Value here"
```

Comment: I can kind of see where you're coming from but unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem.

I need the values in the listbox on the content page to display in the textbox on the masterpage.

Answer (score 0):

So you should run this code on your content page.

I assume your textbox on the masterpage is not in a updatepanel or panel etc. then you need to refer that first. but if not, this should work....

```
Dim tb As Textbox = DirectCast(Master.FindControl("theNameofYourTextBox"), Textbox)
tb.Text = ListBox.Item.Value (or the equivalent for getting the text value in the listbox)
```

Comment: this is close but now my issue is getting the listbox items to display in the textbox.

I don't know how to display the text from the listbox in the textbox on the masterpage.

Comment: What about tb.Text = ListBox.Items(0).Text?

Comment: How many items do you have in your listbox? Can you provide some code?

Comment: The items in the code depends.
To give some reference it's a shopping cart.
The way it works at the moment is that the items are added to an invisible listbox which is then displayed in a textbox as you can't textwrap a listbox.

I will try your suggestion.

Comment: It's now throwing and Object reference not set to an instance of an object runtime error.

I will upload my code block. I won't lie, it's messy. I'm new to asp.net

Comment: Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim SubTotal As Decimal
        Dim lstItems As ListBox = DirectCast(cpcontent.FindControl("lstItems"), ListBox)
        txtCart.Text = lstItems.Items(0).Text
        SubTotal = Session("txtCart")
        lblSubTotal.Text = SubTotal.ToString("c")


    End Sub

Comment: Ok thats because it does not know what the object is. No worries, thats why we have these communities :)

Comment: I also see that you are trying to Findcontrol of the listbox?  You need to find the control on the masterpages from the content pages.

Comment: The code i posted is from the masterpage. 
That page_load sub is taken from the masterpage.

The line throwing the error is line 17.
This is the error code.
Line 15:         Dim SubTotal As Decimal
Line 16:         Dim lstItems As ListBox = DirectCast(cpcontent.FindControl("lstItems"), ListBox)
Line 17:         txtCart.Text = lstItems.Items(0).Text
Line 18:         SubTotal = Session("txtCart")
Line 19:         lblSubTotal.Text = SubTotal.ToString("c")

Comment: Change line 16 to this Dim txtCart As TextBox = DirectCast(Master.FindControl("txtCart OR THE NAME OF YOUR TEXTBOX IN THE MASTERPAGE"), TextBox) , and please, paste code in your post not in the comment area.

Comment: I did that but now it says lstItems is not declared.

Comment: Ok but lets declare this. WHERE is your textbox located? WHERE is your listbox located. As i understood, your listbox is in the content page and your textbox is in your masterpage. Is that correct.

Comment: Yes that is correct.
Listbox is in content page.
Textbox is in masterpage.
I am putting the code in the Page_Load event of the Masterpage.

Comment: You need to run the code from the content page. If you want to get the value from the listbox in the contentpage to the textbox in the masterpage, you have to run your code in the content page.

Comment: Ok i moved the code to the content page and now i have
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Ok, that means that it cannot find the (0) in the array index. if you have 3 items. it would be of index 0,1,2 is your list populated with values?

Comment: The list is only populated as the page is ran.
When i click a button on the page it adds the item to the list.
Then the list is displayed in the textbox.

it uses a for next loop like this

txtCart.Text = ""
        For i = 0 To lstItems.Items.Count - 1
            txtCart.Text &= lstItems.Items.Item(i).ToString() & ""

        Next

Comment: Then you should run the code to put the value in textbox after that. It sounds to me like your listbox is empty when it is trying to get the value.

Comment: I've decided to try a new approach on it but now i need to store the values of the listbox in a session variable... Do you know if this is possible? Thanks for all your help man :).

Comment: Sessions can store pretty much anything. You should consider storing it in your viewstate if the values are small. No problem man!

Comment: How do i go about storing it in the viewstate? Having some problems.

Comment: You can store any object with its values. This page explains it very welll. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx